# Grails URLMappings uses the wrong URL

Tags: grails, url-mapping

[GSP Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3JZU.png)How do I force Grails to use the correct URL in `UrlMappings.groovy` given identical paths, with one ending in `$action` and the other ending in `$id`?  On triggering an action through the GSP file, my program goes into the `id` URL, causing an error.

[Image shows the two URLs in question. I need to trigger the first URL, $action, on click of a button but instead the second URL is triggered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oq8d8.png)

Comment: Maybe add an example?  (Gsp code, UrlMappings.groovy snip)

Comment: added an example, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to have a tough time here as the $id and $action are just variable names until they are assigned. They don't know that you are sending an id or an action, just that the url matches a pattern.  You could do something like this though.

```
"/workflow/**/$siteId/**/$iteration/**/$action?/$id?" (controller:"*****")
```

You would have to always specify your action, `***/list/123` or `***/someAction` would match, but not `***/123`.

You could also probably do some sort of constraint / logic in the mapping to sort things out, but that could get sort of messy.

Answer (score 0):

you can force it by specifying type of request e.g. Post, Put,delete, get etc.

Comment: this did not work as I specified request "$action" as shown in the image above